# google api javascript get logged in user's email

Tags: javascript, google-api

There are many resources and stack overflow questions that are similar but not exactly the same as what I will ask. I will rehash some of the solutions here and explain them.

I have a user that is already logged into Google. By logged in I mean manually logged in and the cookie is present. Not logged in by my application.

I just need to get the email address.

There are 3 ways to do this that I have seen but neither works for me.

Way #1:

```
auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
if (auth2.isSignedIn.get()) {
  var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
  console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
  console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
}
```

Way #2:

```
gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);

gapi.client.load("plus", "v1", function() {
  gapi.client.plus.people.get({ userId: "me" }).execute(function(resp) {
    // Shows profile information
    console.log(resp);
  });
});
```

Way #3:

```
gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', function () {
  gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function (resp) {
    // Shows user email
    console.log(resp.email);
  })
});
```

For Way #2 and Way #3 stack overflow says that you have to use a token and not an api key. But the user is already logged in and I don't have and cannot obtain the token.

How to get the EMAIL of an ALREADY logged in user?

Thanks

Comment: did you find solution?

Comment: basically, you have to take the person's oauth keys (add the scope for People API) and make a call to the Google People API to get the email. I did that in the back end (java) not in javascript.

Answer (score 11):

Though an old question.. this may help .. just incase..

```
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
console.log(profile.getName());
console.log(profile.getEmail());
```

The instance can be initiated by either gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() or gapi.auth2.init(). Based on what is used to instantiate you can use either to get profile details.