# Getting logged-in user's email with Google People API

Tags: javascript, google-people-api

**How do I get the logged-in user's email address with Google People API?**

I am trying to retrieve the logged-in user's email address so I can use it to compare with the data in my app. I have tried various things to get it, but the below code is just returning `undefined`.

```
      function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.people.people.get({
      'resourceName': 'people/me',
      'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names,person.emailAddresses'
    }).then(function(resp) {
      var name = resp.result.names[0].givenName;
      var email = resp.result.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress;
      authorizeButton.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<small rel="' + email + '">Logged in as ' + name + '</small>');
    });
  }
```

Changing it to `var email = resp.result.emailAddresses[0];` results in `[object Object]`.

I also tried using `JSON.parse()` but got the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at (index):285
at h.r2 (cb=gapi.loaded_0:119)
at xs (cb=gapi.loaded_0:122)
at Wq (cb=gapi.loaded_0:122)
at _.C.uea (cb=gapi.loaded_0:121)
at Ap (cb=gapi.loaded_0:115)
at <anonymous>
```

I also tried the methods in [this other unanswered question about the Google People API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185765/google-api-javascript-get-logged-in-users-email).

Comment: Change it back to the setup where you get [object object] and console log the email object and share the log please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please do once

```
console.log(response.result);
```

in here :

```
function makeApiCall() {
    gapi.client.people.people.get({
      'resourceName': 'people/me',
      'requestMask.includeField': 'person.names,person.emailAddresses'
    }).then(function(resp) {

      console.log(response.result);
      var name = resp.result.names[0].givenName;
      //var email = resp.result.emailAddresses[0].emailAddress;
      //authorizeButton.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<small rel="' + email + '">Logged in as ' + name + '</small>');
    });
  }
```

After that use the correct object which ever applicable.

You might want to use

```
var email = resp.result.emailAddresses[0].value;
```

Comment: thanks very much, that's super helpful. `resp.result.emailAddresses[0].value;` was correct, and `console.log(resp.result);` was also really useful.