# How to get profile information from Google Identity Services?

Tags: javascript, google-api-js-client, google-identity

I am using the GAPI async/await example from https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#gapi-asyncawait

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to get information about the user.  I want to get the user's name and email.

I believe the preferred solution is to get the user's info from id_token.  I have added the scopes "profile email openid", but I am still not getting an id_token returned.

I also tried loading a gapi client for "oauth2" and "plus" to query the profile info but was also unsuccessful with that.

This is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>GAPI with GIS async/await</h1>
  <button id="showEventsBtn" onclick="showEvents();">Show Calendar</button><br><br>
  <button id="revokeBtn" onclick="revokeToken();">Revoke access token</button>

  <script>

    const gapiLoadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gapiLoadOkay = resolve;
      gapiLoadFail = reject;
    });
    const gisLoadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      gisLoadOkay = resolve;
      gisLoadFail = reject;
    });

    var tokenClient;

    (async () => {
      document.getElementById("showEventsBtn").style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("revokeBtn").style.visibility = "hidden";

      // First, load and initialize the gapi.client
      await gapiLoadPromise;
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // NOTE: the 'auth2' module is no longer loaded.
        gapi.load('client', { callback: resolve, onerror: reject });
      });
      await gapi.client.init({
        // NOTE: OAuth2 'scope' and 'client_id' parameters have moved to initTokenClient().
      })
        .then(function () {  // Load the Calendar API discovery document.
          gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest');
          gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/people/v1/rest');
          gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/plus/v1/rest');
          gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/oauth2/v1/rest');
        });

      // Now load the GIS client
      await gisLoadPromise;
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
            scope: 'profile email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
            prompt: 'consent',
            callback: '',  // defined at request time in await/promise scope.
          });
          resolve();
        } catch (err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });

      document.getElementById("showEventsBtn").style.visibility = "visible";
      document.getElementById("revokeBtn").style.visibility = "visible";
    })();

    async function getToken(err) {

      if (err.result.error.code == 401 || (err.result.error.code == 403) &&
        (err.result.error.status == "PERMISSION_DENIED")) {

        // The access token is missing, invalid, or expired, prompt for user consent to obtain one.
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            // Settle this promise in the response callback for requestAccessToken()
            tokenClient.callback = (resp) => {
              if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                reject(resp);
              }
              // GIS has automatically updated gapi.client with the newly issued access token.
              console.log('gapi.client access token JSON: ' + JSON.stringify(gapi.client.getToken()));
              console.log(gapi.client.getToken());
              resolve(resp);
            };
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
        });
      } else {
        // Errors unrelated to authorization: server errors, exceeding quota, bad requests, and so on.
        throw new Error(err);
      }
    }

    function showEvents() {

      // Try to fetch a list of Calendar events. If a valid access token is needed,
      // prompt to obtain one and then retry the original request.
      gapi.client.calendar.events.list({ 'calendarId': 'primary' })
        .then(calendarAPIResponse => console.log(JSON.stringify(calendarAPIResponse)))
        .catch(err => getToken(err))  // for authorization errors obtain an access token
        .then(retry => gapi.client.calendar.events.list({ 'calendarId': 'primary' }))
        .then(calendarAPIResponse => console.log(JSON.stringify(calendarAPIResponse)))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));   // cancelled by user, timeout, etc.
    }

    function revokeToken() {
      let cred = gapi.client.getToken();
      if (cred !== null) {
        google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(cred.access_token, () => { console.log('Revoked: ' + cred.access_token) });
        gapi.client.setToken('');
      }
    }

  </script>

  <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoadOkay()"
    onerror="gapiLoadFail(event)"></script>
  <script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoadOkay()"
    onerror="gisLoadFail(event)"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the specific error you're encountering? Also, the `authorization code flow` is more recommended in terms of user security and has more offline functionalities.

Comment: Hi @CatherineO.  I do not have an exact error that I'm troubleshooting.  My issue is I have not found a way to get the user's basic information like name and email.  When I examine the response from gapi.client.getToken() id_token is not there.  So I cannot use that.  Then I've also tried the ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185765/google-api-javascript-get-logged-in-users-email but none of them get me any profile info as well.  
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance() - returns null
I don't have an API key so I cannot do `gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY)`

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this again and answer #3 from [google api javascript get logged in user's email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185765/google-api-javascript-get-logged-in-users-email) worked for me this time.

Note that in my example above I had added:

```
gapi.client.load('https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/oauth2/v1/rest');
```

that was not in the original example that I used, after that I am able to get the user's info with:

```
gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function (resp) {
    // Shows user email
    console.log(resp);
  })
```

or

```
(await gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get()).result
```

Comment: This may be deprecated. I tried out this method and received this HTTP 403 response from Google: `Requests to this API openidconnect.googleapis.com method google.identity.oauth2.openidconnect.v1.OpenIdConnectService.GetLegacyUserInfo are blocked.`

Comment: I just tried it again and its still working for me.  On my network tab, I don't see any calls to openidconnect.googleapis.com?  Do you have any additional code that may be making an additional request that gets that 403 response?