# Google Identity Service - How Obtain Profile / Email Information From Authenticated user

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-signin, google-api-js-client

I'm porting over some existing js code authenticating with the google cloud platform (as they are migrating to a new set of libraries).

(migration guide: https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis)

I'm struggling with getting a hold of the player's profile (to obtain their email).

The old approach would be along the lines of this (but as it says, it is now deprecated - I've been reading the new docs but it mostly surrounds getting authorized/authenticate and not the follow on from that):
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people

e.g.

```
var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
var email = profile.getEmail();
```

In my new code I've have the access token, via the new approach:

```
    client_id: vm.clientId,
    scope: SCOPE,
    callback: (tokenResponse) => {
        if (tokenResponse && tokenResponse.access_token) {
            access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;

            // HERE??? HOW DO I GET THE PROFILE?

        }
    }
})
```

(largely taken from https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model)

I've seen this mentioned elsewhere but it doesn't work in my situation at least:

```
gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get().execute(function (resp) {
   console.log(resp);
})
```

([How to get profile information from Google Identity Services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72765524/how-to-get-profile-information-from-google-identity-services))

I've read via the migration guide: 'Instead, use direct references to credential sub-fields in the new JWT CredentialResponse object to work with user profile data.' but don't know how to get this Credentialresponse?
(https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration#token_response)

---

Comment: where did you get that code?  can i see a link to the docs

Comment: Thanks - I've edited the original post to include some links. The code is largely taken from https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model

Comment: Take the access token and use it to either request profile info from the userinfo endpoint or the people api assuming that you have requested the profile scope

Comment: Thank you - I think I might have it... just testing and will post a more detailed summary / sample code.

Answer (score 6):

You can follow these steps that I had to undertake to achieve the entire flow using `Javascript`.

First create a `button` that will hold the HTML element:

```
<button id="btnGoogleSignIn" style="border:none;background: none;"> </button>
```

You can then use the below script and associated functions in which I am getting the JWT token from Google and then decoding it to get the required information out like email address etc. Note that I am calling the onSignInGSI as callback on the button initialization.

```
<script>  
    function decodeJwtResponseFromGoogleAPI(token) {
            let base64Url = token.split('.')[1]
            let base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
            let jsonPayload = 
           decodeURIComponent(atob(base64).split('').map(function (c) {
                return '%' + ('00' + 
           c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            }).join(''));
            return JSON.parse(jsonPayload)
        }

    function onSignInGSI(response) {
        //console.log(response)
        responsePayload = decodeJwtResponseFromGoogleAPI(response.credential);
        console.log("ID: " + responsePayload.sub);
        console.log('Full Name: ' + responsePayload.name);
        console.log('Given Name: ' + responsePayload.given_name);
        console.log('Family Name: ' + responsePayload.family_name);
        console.log("Image URL: " + responsePayload.picture);
        console.log("Email: " + responsePayload.email);
    }

    window.onload = function () {

        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: client_id,
            context: 'signin',
            callback: onSignInGSI
        });

        google.accounts.id.prompt();
        
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("btnGoogleSignIn"), 
        {
            type: "standard",
            text: "signin_with",
            logo_alignment: "left",
            width: 375
        });
    };
</script>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, on your other similar answer [stackoverflow.com/a/75382705/4011467], you've added a parameter for **prompt** method later on. Can you explain "Why is the prompt not displayed in certain situations", and "what is **skipped moment**" please?

Comment: @CevdetHamarat The skipped moment occurs when the One Tap prompt is closed by an auto cancel, a manual cancel, or when Google fails to issue a credential, such as when the selected session has signed out of Google. Now in such cases we manually invalidate the `g_state` cookie. But more most reasons, the prompt is not displayed because you have not added the domain to the `Authorised Javascript Origins`. You will a get `GSI Logger` error on the console for such cases.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a function like this works in my situation:

```
function getUserProfileData(accessToken) {
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo`;
        request.addEventListener("loadend", function() {
            const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            if (this.status === 200) {
                resolve(response);
            } else {
                reject(this, response);
            }
        });
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
        request.send();
    });

    promise.then(function(response) {
        var email = response.email;
    }, function(errorMessage) {
        // TODO: print error
    });
}
```

This returns a json that contains the following properties:

- email
- email_verified
- family_name
- given_name
- hd
- name
- picture
- sub