# I keep getting a [GSI_LOGGER]: Parameter client_id is not set correctly. when trying to implement the Google Identity SignIn

Tags: google-signin, google-identity

Followed googles steps and got generated code as shown below, but on page load, the console shows [GSI_LOGGER]: Parameter client_id. Can you help with ideas on how to fix this issue.

this is generated code i added to my login page

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="clientID.apps.googleusercontent.com"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-login_uri="http://localhost:8080/web/admin.html"
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
    data-type="standard"
    data-shape="pill"
    data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
    data-size="large"
    data-logo_alignment="left">
```

Comment: I can give you an answer if you are using the `Javascript` version of the new implementation of the library.

Comment: Sure lets have it, i am open to using javascript

Comment: You can refer to this answer for the `Javascript` implementation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75283256/google-identity-service-how-obtain-profile-email-information-from-authentica/75383207#75383207